# Elasticsearch Date Historam with first document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to write a query which will return first entry of every month but I am not able to find anything can any one please help me with it .

i tried the below query but it return number of documents in that month not the first document in that month

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "id" : "1" }
        },"size":0,
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).